# Using .NET Core's MongoDB.Driver with CosmosDB, DeleteManyAsync() call results in "Request rate is large" error

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

So I understand that a CosmosDB Request Unit is an abstract unit of cost that includes various system resources.

With that I just didn't expect that a DeleteManyAsync() call with a filter of "anything before a particular timestamp" would result in a request rate error.  Is this really that expensive for CosmosDB to do, or is the MongoDB.Driver being expensive behind the scenes, issuing a delete request one-at-a-time or something?

I suppose some additional indexes on the collection could reduce the RU cost?

Comment: The response headers from the request to cosmosdb should include some more information on RU usage if you can view them.  You could probably inspect how the delete is implemented, too.

Comment: I suppose what I'm looking for is a BatchSize parameter in DeleteOptions, much like what I see in FindOptions, so that it can be set in such a way to not run into RU usage issues.  There is no BatchSize parameter.  As far as I can tell there's no real good way to do a bulk delete without fetching the records first and then manually chunking them up.

Comment: Yeah.  I don't think that CosmosDB supports bulk delete.  Not even a flush database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I basically ended up doing was to call DeleteManyAsync() with WriteConcern of "unacknowledged".  The call comes back immediately and then I check the record count.  It seems to delete as many as it can before it hits the RU limit.  So I check if all the records were deleted.  If not, delay a little and repeat the process.

Pretty ugly but nothing else comes to mind.